# how to Convert ASM to c++?

Tags: c++, cheat-engine

I have this cheat engine script:

```
[Enable]
009516C2:
jns 0095138F

[Disable]
009516C2:    
je 0095138F
```

I want to convert it to C++, Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean "Convert it to C++". Do you mean you want to write a C++ program which does the same thing as the cheat engine script when run under the cheat engine?

Comment: Yes, I can just run this script, not in a cheat engine, just in a trainer made in c ++

Comment: What processor is the assembly language for?  The `je` could be *jump if even* or *jump if equal*.

Comment: What's the comparison that sets the condition codes?  Need the information in order to set up the `if` statement.

Comment: i dont know how i check it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is x86-32bit asm. The `je` means *jump-if-equal* in this scenario.
@GavrielSinvani The difference between `jns` and `jne` is a single byte. In order to implement this in c++, you need to change the byte within the process. This can be done using `WriteProcessMemory` and `VirtualProtectEx`. In order to enable, you will need to write `'\x89'` to 00951390, and to disable you will have to write `'\x84'` to the same address. This changes the opcodes from `je` (0F 84) to `jns` (0F 89) and vice versa.